# submit a data in a python script when it run by node js

Tags: python, node.js, command-line-interface, telegram

First of all i'm sorry for my weak English

I have a python code to create a cli account for telegram as the following:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.raw import functions

api_id = someNumber
api_hash = "someHash"

with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash) as app:
    print('Bot is online...')
```

I use a node.js code to run python script as the following:

```
if(command == 'run cli'){
     var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
     var process = spawn('python', ["python/hello.py"]);
     process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
           console.log(data.toString());
     });
}
```

The output is:
`Enter phone number or bot token:`

How can i give it my phone number from node.js?

Actually when i run the python script with cmd by "python hello.py", it wants me the phone number and i write it then i press enter key and finish. so easy.

But in this situation i don't know what should i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the easiest way (if possible) is to modify your python script to accept command-line arguments, through `sys.argv`.

So you would modify your python program to this:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.raw import functions
import sys # we need the sys module to access these arguments I'm talking about

phone_number = sys.argv[1] # the phone number will be the first (and only, I'm assuming) argument. You can pass multiple arguments, and access them with `sys.argv[2]`, `sys.argv[3]`...etc.
api_id = someNumber
api_hash = "someHash"

with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash, phone_number=phone_number) as app: # pass the phone number to Client
    print('Bot is online...')
```

Now you have the phone number stored in the variable `phone_number` and it is passed to `Client`, so you should be good on the Python end.

In your node script, though, you will have to actually *pass* the phone number as an argument, and you can do that by adding arguments as elements of the array of which `"python/hello.py"` is a part of, like so:

```
if(command == 'run cli'){
     var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
     var process = spawn('python', ["python/hello.py", "PHONE NUMBER GOES HERE"]);
     process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
           console.log(data.toString());
     });
}
```

...and you should be good.

*Note that I have not tested this code yet.*

Comment: thank you for your help. But it does not work because when the python script runs by node.js it doesn't need any args. actually it requests for the phone number after it runs.

Comment: Okay is it possible to pass the phone number from a variable in the python program to the input? Or do you have to manually input it?

Comment: What you say is my problem exactly. I don't know much about python and how can i pass my phone number to the python script as an input automatically.

Comment: So I just looked at the docs and you should be able to pass the phone number along with `api_id` and `api_hash`, like so: `with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash, phone_number=phone_number) as app:` If the phone number doesn't change, you can just define it in your python program and pass it in place of `phone_number` so you save the hassle of passing it as an argument from the node script